# The name for an assumption made for the sake of contradiction - the marked assumption?

Tags: word-choice

To be clear, I am a mathematician first.

*What is the name (or adjective) for an assumption made for the sake of contradiction?*

To be clear, I'm in search of an expression in the form "a(n) $\underline{\quad \quad \quad \quad}$ assumption".

I liked the suggestion "the marked assumption", found in the comments to this mathoverflow question asked by Me: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362848/the-name-for-an-assumption-made-for-the-sake-of-contradiction. Unlike Willie Wong's suggestion the "contradictive assumption", the "marked assumption" only partially suggests the nature of the expression. This is hard to fix unless the expression is made standard.

An advantage of the "marked assumption" is that it can serve double-duty: Even in cases where the truth of the assumption is unknown, the expression is still relevant. This is particularly notable in the study of the Riemann Hypothesis where the Riemann Hypothesis is occasionally assumed and consequences derived therefrom. If the marked assumption holds, then all we have done is discover consistent structure. If the marked assumption fails, then our presumptive work can just be seen as a search for a contradiction.

P.S. The comma and period placements are deliberate.

Comment: What follows *an expression in the form of* makes no sense to me at all. Please rephrase it in natural language. That aside, are you talking about something that's the equivalent of a devil's advocate statement? The final paragraph doesn't make it clear that the proposed assumption is in contradiction to anything else. In fact, if I didn't know from the title of the question that it was to be something contrary, I would assume the question was only asking about a single hypothesis. Where is the main or primary assumption that this other one is in contrast to?

Comment: @JasonBassford Omit the "$\underline{\quad \quad \quad \quad}$" and imagine a blanked underline. That particular choice was Just(,) a choice of style. For the rest, try consulting a mathematician with a little more patience :p

Comment: So, you're in search of an expression in the form __ ? I'm afraid that doesn't make sense either. But the third paragraph aside (which I will have to ignore for now), it's still not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm in search of an expression in the form "a(n) _ assumption", in your style.

Comment: Perhaps coin your answer? Contra-axiomatic?